# How do I still display the numbers in the array that are not divisible by 3 or 5?

Tags: javascript

My code is actually correct to an extent; when I `return C`, I get `[9, 13, 24]`, which is correct (numbers divisible by 3 and 5 in `array1` are added to corresponding element in `array2`).

The issue is that I still want `[1, 2, 4]` from `array1` to be included. In other words, I want the expected log to be: `[1, 2, 9, 4, 13, 24]`

```js
function mergingTripletsAndQuints(array1, array2) {
  let c = []
  for (let i = 0; Math.max(i < array1.length, i < array2.length); i++) {
    if (array1[i] % 3 == 0 || array1[i] % 5 == 0) {
      c.push(array1[i] + array2[i])
    }
  }
  return c
}

console.log(mergingTripletsAndQuints(
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15], [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
// expected log [1, 2, 9, 4, 13, 24]
```

Comment: Pretty sure `Math.max()` wasn't designed to work with Booleans. Did you mean `i < Math.max(array1.length, array2.length)`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you meant `i < Math.max(array1.length, array2.length)`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I am a beginner, so I am not sure if there is a difference between the two. Either way, I still got the same result, which is `[9, 13, 24]`

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function mergingTripletsAndQuints(array1, array2) {
      let c = [];

      for (let i = 0; Math.max(i < array1.length, i < array2.length); i++) {
        if (array1[i] % 3 === 0 || array1[i] % 5 === 0) {
          c.push(array1[i] + array2[i]);
        } else {
          c.push(array1[i]);
        }
      }
      return c;
    }

    console.log(mergingTripletsAndQuints([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15], [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

try this.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Question though: doesn't the `else` statement mean that it will be executed only if the `if` statement is not met? in this case, to my knowledge, both `if` and `else` statements are executed

Comment: Correct. In your case the first test you wanted to store in the c array any number that are `array1[i] % 3 === 0 || array1[i] % 5 === 0`. In addition, you wanted to have other items that are in the array1. So when loop will run `if` statement is not passed it will go to `else` statement. Does this make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

if (array1[i] % 3 == 0 || array1[i] % 5 == 0) {  -> this happens 3 times not 6. so you must push outside the if  else {push arr[i]}